# How do I show and hide some elements in a div on hover?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show buttons in a div when I hover over the div and hide the text inside it, and then hide the buttons but show the div's text. I keep getting the undefined error. What did I do wrong?

> Error:
>
> coreScript.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of
> undefined
>
> at showButton (coreScript.js:12)
>
> at HTMLDivElement.onmouseover (Core.html:33)
>
> coreScript.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of
> undefined
>
> at hideButton (coreScript.js:6)
>
> at HTMLDivElement.onmouseout (Core.html:33)

```js
function hideButton() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('xOne').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementsByClassName('xTen').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementsByClassName('all').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementsByClassName('name').style.display = 'block';
}

function showButton() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('xOne').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementsByClassName('xTen').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementsByClassName('all').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementsByClassName('name').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.main-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 198px;
  max-width: 198px;
  min-height: 33px;
  max-height: 33px;
  font-size: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: boxShadowNone 0.1s;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div" onmouseover="showButton()" onmouseout=" hideButton()" onclick="sell()" id="sellMeat">
  <div class="name">SELL MEAT</div>
  <div class="xOne" style="display: none;">x1</div>
  <div class="xTen" style="display: none;">x10</div>
  <div class="all" style="display: none;">All</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="main-div" onmouseover="showButton()" onmouseout="changeText(this, 'SELL LEATHER', '16px'); hideButton()" onclick="sell()" id="sellLeather">
  <div class="name">SELL Leather</div>
  <div class="xOne" style="display: none;">x1</div>
  <div class="xTen" style="display: none;">x10</div>
  <div class="all" style="display: none;">All</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`  which is an array-like object of all child elements.

Replace `getElementsByClassName(class)` by `querySelector(.class)` for right behavior.

You can also do `getElementsByClassName(class)[0]` to access the element but I think `querySelector` works well for this particular use-case.

```js
function hideButton(e) {
  const element = e.currentTarget;
  element.querySelector('.xOne').style.display = 'none';
  element.querySelector('.xTen').style.display = 'none';
  element.querySelector('.all').style.display = 'none';
  element.querySelector('.name').style.display = 'block';
}

function showButton(e) {
 const element = e.currentTarget;
  element.querySelector('.xOne').style.display = 'block';
  element.querySelector('.xTen').style.display = 'block';
  element.querySelector('.all').style.display = 'block';
  element.querySelector('.name').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.main-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 198px;
  max-width: 198px;
  min-height: 33px;
  max-height: 33px;
  font-size: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: boxShadowNone 0.1s;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div" onmouseover="showButton(event)" onmouseout=" hideButton(event)" id="sellMeat">
  <div class="name">SELL MEAT</div>
  <div class="xOne" style="display: none;">x1</div>
  <div class="xTen" style="display: none;">x10</div>
  <div class="all" style="display: none;">All</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="main-div" onmouseover="showButton(event)" onmouseout=" hideButton(event)" id="sellLeather">
  <div class="name">SELL Leather</div>
  <div class="xOne" style="display: none;">x1</div>
  <div class="xTen" style="display: none;">x10</div>
  <div class="all" style="display: none;">All</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It shows an error when i hover over the second button, how can that be fixed?

Comment: You haven't included the code for those functions in your question. That's why.

Comment: I mean it doesnt show the xOne, xTen and all in the sell leather button at all. Do I need to create another func for those too?

Comment: Updated my code. Removed the functions which aren't defined as well as instead of querying on `document`, now we are querying on the currentTarget i.e. on which the handlers are attached and just trying to see query it's child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Lakshya Thakur gave you various great solutions. As he said,  **getElementsByClassName** returns a collection; but if you want to apply the style to all elements with a specific class (in case you will have more than one in the future) you can apply the style inside a loop.

```
function hideButton() {
      document.getElementsByClassName('xOne').forEach(
                   element => element.style.display = 'none'; 
      );
}
```

I dind't try the code, but this is the logic.